# How to detect changes in a webpage and play a sound with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I have a javascript code which refreshes a webpage every 2 seconds to check if there is any update from the database.

What I would like it to do is to play a sound when the webpage display new things.

Below is the html file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false
        });
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {$('#loading').load('index.php').fadeIn("slow");}, 2000);
    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="loading"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to Javascript

Comment: get a response from your server in json, if any change then play sound

Comment: play sound using HTML Audio tag whenever you will get a success response from a server.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is custom implementation like HTTP ETag. 
It should look like this:

Extract version no from html sent by PHP script, pass this version no to each ajax request, server will check both versions and provide proper responses to client.

If server replies with

1) http status code 200 => web page is changed => play sound.

2) http status code 304 => web page is not changed